# Only add the "edited by" label for big changes, and not "Edit tags"

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, edits

Editing tags is a minor change; "Edited by ..." should be added only for big edits/ improvements.

Personally, I find "Edited by ... Kilroy" distracting, not helpful.

Comment: With the privilege "moderator tools" https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools  I get inline tag editing. I like to know if tags has changed so I don't step on any one else changes. So if anything, if the "edited" indicator is removed then I rather have it based on reputation.

Comment: I suppose one could argue that retagging a question is not really editing the question. I usually click on "Edited by ..." to see what improvements were made to the question and I am usually disappointed when all that was done was a change to the tags. Good and appropriate tags are important, but my expectation when I see "Edited by ..." is that the question itself has been improved.